# Count rows within a group, but also from global result set: performance issue

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have a table with log records. Each log record is represented by a status (`open` or `closed`) and a `date`:

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
  id          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  status      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  inserted_at DATE NOT NULL
);
```

I need to get a daily report with a following information:

1. how many log records with `status = open` were created,
2. how many log records with `status = closed` were created,
3. how many log records with `status = open` exist to this day, including this day.

Here's a sample report output:

```
    day     | created | closed | total_open
------------+---------+--------+------------
 2017-01-01 |       2 |      0 |          2
 2017-01-02 |       2 |      1 |          3
 2017-01-03 |       1 |      1 |          3
 2017-01-04 |       1 |      0 |          4
 2017-01-05 |       1 |      0 |          5
 2017-01-06 |       1 |      0 |          6
 2017-01-07 |       1 |      0 |          7
 2017-01-08 |       0 |      1 |          6
 2017-01-09 |       0 |      0 |          6
 2017-01-10 |       0 |      0 |          6
(10 rows)
```

---

I solved this in a very "dirty" way:

```
INSERT INTO logs (status, inserted_at) VALUES
  ('created', '2017-01-01'),
  ('created', '2017-01-01'),
  ('closed', '2017-01-02'),
  ('created', '2017-01-02'),
  ('created', '2017-01-02'),
  ('created', '2017-01-03'),
  ('closed', '2017-01-03'),
  ('created', '2017-01-04'),
  ('created', '2017-01-05'),
  ('created', '2017-01-06'),
  ('created', '2017-01-07'),
  ('closed', '2017-01-08');

  SELECT days.day,
         count(case when logs.inserted_at  = days.day AND logs.status = 'created' then 1 end) as created,
         count(case when logs.inserted_at  = days.day AND logs.status = 'closed' then 1 end) as closed,
         count(case when logs.inserted_at <= days.day AND logs.status = 'created' then 1 end) -
         count(case when logs.inserted_at <= days.day AND logs.status = 'closed' then 1 end) as total
    FROM (SELECT day::date FROM generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-01-10'::date, '1 day'::interval) day) days,
         logs
GROUP BY days.day
ORDER BY days.day;
```

Also (posted it on [gist](https://gist.github.com/gmile/6b85cede1051a532c0ec52b64b1cd92d) for brevity), and would like to improve the solution.

Right now `explain` for my query reveals some ridiculous cost numbers that that I would like to minimize (I don't have indexes yet).

**How an efficient query to achieve the report above would look like?**

Comment: I'm afraid that dirty way is ok. look into `crosstab` also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Apart from `total_open`, your query is a simple aggregation (`GROUP BY`) and I see, you've already met with `generate_series()`. `total_open` is a running sum (of `created`). You can calculate it with [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html): `sum(created) over (order by day)`.

Comment: BTW your query is a really clever way of simulating window functions (at least on those RDBMS where it is not supported). But actually using window functions should be more effective.

Comment: @pozs, thank you but I'm not sure I understand your example with `sum`. I'm trying to use `sum` with `over()`, but keep getting different errors back. Can you please post a full query using window functions, the way you see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select s.*, sum(created - closed) over (order by inserted_at)
from   (select    inserted_at,
                  count(status) filter (where status = 'created') created,
                  count(status) filter (where status = 'closed')  closed
        from      (select d::date inserted_at
                   from   generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-01-10'::date, '1 day'::interval) d) d
        left join logs using (inserted_at)
        group by  inserted_at) s
```

http://rextester.com/GFRRP71067

Also, an index on `(inserted_at, status)` could help you a lot with this query.

*Note*: `count(...) filter (where ...)` is really just a fancy way to write `count(case when ... then ... [else null] end)`.

Comment: `FILTER`, `USING`, a proper usage of a window function... So much to learn from your example, thank you!